# A continuous crawl set in powershell does not seem to be crawling content

Tags: 2013, powershell, search

A week ago I created a continuous crawl in SharePoint by using this script:

```
GET Search Service Application
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

#Get the Crawl Content Source
$cs = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity "Local SharePoint sites"

#Enable Continuous Crawls
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Identity $cs -EnableContinuousCrawls $True

#Set the crawl interval to 10 minutes
$ssa.SetProperty("ContinuousCrawlInterval", 10)
$ssa.Update()
```

After running the script I could see that the crawl was working.  Recently updated content appeared in searches.  However, after a few days, I noticed that items added after enabling continuous crawls were not appearing in search results.

I ran this script to give me some information on the status:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Identity 'Local SharePoint Sites' -SearchApplication $ssa | Format-List -Property *
```

...and received this back:

```
CrawlState               : Idle
CrawlCompleted           : 5/17/2018 3:53:48 PM
CrawlStarted             : 5/17/2018 3:06:28 PM
SharePointCrawlBehavior  : CrawlVirtualServers
EnableContinuousCrawls   : True
FollowDirectories        : False
Type                     : SharePoint
DeleteCount              : 299
ErrorCount               : 15508
LevelHighErrorCount      : 0
SuccessCount             : 35373
WarningCount             : 1138
Parent                   : {Local SharePoint sites}
StartAddresses           : {https://<servername>/}
Id                       : 1
Tag                      : 
Name                     : Local SharePoint sites
FullCrawlSchedule        : 
IncrementalCrawlSchedule : Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.DailySchedule
CrawlStatus              : Idle
ContinuousCrawlStatus    : Crawling
CrawlPriority            : Normal
RefreshCrawls            : Enabled
```

Because I'm not receiving search results from content I've added since the crawl has been created, and since the value of *CrawlCompleted* is a week old, I feel that the Continuous Crawl are *not* truly active as I thought they were.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to truly enable continuous crawls through PowerShell?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen capture shows a very large number of errors. These are usually caused from the crawler not having the proper permissions. Check the Crawl Logs to find the cause of the errors.

Have you identified a pattern for what's not getting indexed? A certain site, library, document type, etc.?

Comment: I was able to dramatically reduce the error I experienced in the crawls by ensuring all necessary user rights were granted to the content access account.  There about 4 or 5 user rights.  Once thos were added the number of errors I encountered dropped dramatically.